# Displaying container elements in a dialog box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dialog

This question applies to the Resource Viewer/Editor of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional. It's more of a design question than a programming question but since dialog boxes are a part of program design, I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask.

I have a couple of structs like this:

```
struct Car
{
    const char* m_color;
    int m_miles;
};


struct CarGarage
{
    std::vector<Car> m_cars;

    int m_capacity;
    bool m_freeparking;
};
```

I would like to create a dialog box to edit a car garage along with any car(s) in it. Since a car garage can have a variable number of cars, I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to design the dialog box.

So far, I have a simple dialog box designed to edit information for a single car. I would like the `Edit CarGarage` dialog box to list all of the cars and provide a mechanism to edit each car if the user chooses to do so.

Is there any utility in the Toolbox designed to deal with situations like this? Does an elegant solution exist for displaying a variable number of container elements in a dialog box?

Comment: You're going to need to deal with this in code -- create controls for each item you need with `CreateWindow` in your `WM_INITDIALOG` message handler (and possibly resize the dialog box etc.).

Comment: What if I wanted to display only one car at a time and have a "Next" and "Previous" option to scroll though rather than displaying them all at once. Would any of the utilities in the toolbox be more elegant than a standard button for "Next" or "Previous" options?